# Display jQuery custom attribute in alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm trying to display the jQuery custom attribute in alert or console.

I tried using `console.log()` to log my custom data attribute but its not displaying the value.

I'm trying to display this value data-something, here's my code:

When I tried to display the value in alert it shows undefined; how to fix it?

```
// create a UL element
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');

// add some LI elements
ul.append(
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="panda">panda bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="koala">koala bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="wallaby" data-type="kangaroo">kangaroo</li>')
);

// this won't work because our UL is not in the dom yet
console.log($('.bear').length); //=> 0

// let's just pick the bears in our UL using our UL as the context
var bears = $('.bear', ul);
console.log(bears); //=> [li.bear, li.bear]

// lets loop through and see data attributes
bears.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-type'));
});
//=> "panda"
//=> "koala"
```

Comment: You didn't insert the element in the DOM or assign it to a variable...

Comment: Yes, don't forget to update some element's html:
`$('.status_holder').html(statusHtmlArr.join(''))` 
first. Then your alert will show stuff.

Comment: @elclanrs: thanks for your reply...can you please update the code...its confusing...

Answer (score 1):

I have changed few of the code !

```
<div id="statusHtml">

</div>

<script>

// it will help to get statusHtml div tag using jquery.
var statusHtmlArr=$("#statusHtml");

$.each($('.loc-li'),funciton(){

  alert("print the value in alert" + $(this).attr('data-test'));

});

/*OR*/

alert("print the value in alert" + $('.loc-li').attr('data-test'));

</script>
```

**to show the attribute in jquery you have to use "attr()" function**

**[Check Fiffle](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Comment: thanks for ur reply...i tested ur code but still it shows undefined

Comment: Can u provide fiddle?  As I think I can able to solve ur issue

Comment: i am using the value from html in another function like this var locID = d.value;console.log(locID); if i get the value in dat-test attribute how should i pass into locID variable